# how to customize login page in Odoo 14

Tags: python, authentication, odoo, customization

how i can customize login page and add a field "contact_no" (already inherited res.users and added contact_no), when user press [Log in] button, this *will authenticate the user using contact_no first*

please help.

below is xml (template) code to modify login screen ( thanks to @Yurii Razumovskyi ) this code is working fine and showing 'Contact No' field before Email, **but i can't figure out other required changes for controller and model**.

```
<template id="login" inherit_id="web.login" name="Custom Login" >
     <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('field-login')]" position="before">
         <div class="form-group field-contact-no"> 
             <label for="contact_no">Contact No</label> 
             <input type="text" placeholder="Contact No" name="contact_no" t-att-value="contact_no" id="contact_no" t-attf-class="form-control #{'form-control-sm' if form_small else ''}" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocapitalize="off"/> 
          </div> 
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: any hope to get answer?

Comment: Please explain how you need to authenticate the user using contact no first?

Comment: thanks @Kenly, as mentioned, instead of default Email and Password, I want to modify default Login form and add "contact_no" for authentication, now instead of Email I want odoo login mechanism to use "contact_no and password" to authenticate. the field "contact_no" has already been added in odoo Signup form and it sets as mandatory 'required=True'. hope that it clear.

Comment: for " using contact_no first " it was added IF odoo can have mutiple fields for authentication process like " if-then-sel ". no problem for this, but it should do authentication for "contact_no" at least.

Comment: You need to override the [web_login](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L916) method.

Comment: thanks again, i have inheritted and modified just Label "Your Email" to "Your Contact #" because it accepts everything for the field "login". further functionalities are same default. now it needs to check that user should enter a phone/mobile number. please advise.

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the [web_login](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L916) method and use [phonenumbers](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/phone_validation/tools/phone_validation.py#L18) to check if the `Contact No` is a valid phone number.

Check if a user enter a valid phone number then add a condition to the if block:

```
valid_phone_number = False
if 'contact_no' in request.params:
    number = request.params['contact_no']
    try:
        phonenumbers.parse(number, region="US", keep_raw_input=True)
        valid_phone_number = True
    except phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException as e:
        values['error'] = _('Unable to parse %(phone)s: %(error)s', phone=number, error=str(e))
```

It will render the `login` and return the result to show the error.

Comment: thanks a bunch @Kenly, will check this to validate phone number and give feedback. :)

Comment: hi @Kenly, created function in python file, under @api.depends('contact_no'), Pycharm is showing an error " Unresolved reference 'values' " what i am missing? any odoo / phthon library? i have imported " phonenumbers " python library. also UserError from odoo.exceptions.

Comment: The code above is valid in the `web_login` controller method. If the contact no is not a valid user an error will be shown in the login page.

Comment: sorry i failed to convey, Pycharm is showing error when I copy & paste this code, pycharm not recognizing it ( the last line of your code first word  " values " ). cannot run the signup page with this code.

Comment: The values are declared in [web_login](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L925), or you can just do `values = request.params.copy()`.

Comment: Did you succeed to set the validation?

Comment: hi @Kenly, i failed yet, created api.constrain in model but not worked.      @api.constrains('contact_no')
    def _check_contactno(self):
        valid_contact_no = False
        if 'contact_no' in self:
            number = self['contact_no']
            try:
                phonenumbers.parse(number, region="US", keep_raw_input=True)
                valid_contact_no = True
            except phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException as e:
                values = _('Unable to parse %(phone)s: %(error)s', phone=number, error=str(e))

Comment: Why not validating the `Contact No` when the user submits the login form (In the controller)?

Comment: first i installed phonenumbers library using pip3 install and imported it in above model import phonenumbers. may be my mistke(s) due to limited knowledge.

Comment: as mentioned in my opening post here, i am not able to inherit and extend the controllers.

Comment: Can you consider changing the type of the input field to validate the phone number when submitting the form?

Comment: it is type of Char and it is not possible for me to change the type.

Comment: No, In the login form. Change the `input` type to validate phone numbers using HTML.

Comment: for HTML validation i can just restrict to use numbers, min & max length.

Comment: Try to add the following attributes``type="tel"`` and ``pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"`` to validate the phone numbers in the following format: ``123-456-7890``

Comment: yes, it works fine, thank you and appreciate your passions to teach us, to help us :) regards